# Jquerytool dateinput dropdown change loses values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, date, jquery-tools

I'm having an issue with the date input from jQuery Tools.

When I click the input text it shows me everything correct,
 [image: This is when I see the plugin by the first time]

But when I change the values from the year or month I'll get this:

[image]

I thought it was from my project, because I could have done something wrong, but I tested in the official website and I get the same behavior. I'm using Safari at the moment but it does the same thing in my other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by another developer.

Here is the link:
[fix dateinput selectors](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/commit/8059b6dddddd58d6e7a34c831968b3f4b3aabc8b)

Answer (score 0):

I just find out that is a confirmed Bug.

Here is the Link,
https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/662